# TypeError: this.state.details.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-props

There is no error in the code and when I am populating object then no issue but while doing mapping and other operations it shows like this. And also I have consoled this component at that time I have seen that it's consoled 2 times. Why it is consoling 2 times. I am totally confused.

code is given below

code:-(Banner)

```
export default class Banner extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      passedId: this.props.data.id,
      details:'',
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    let data={
      id:this.state.passedId
    }
    axios.post('/getoneartist' ,data)
    .then(res=>{
      this.setState({details:res.data})
      this.forceUpdate()
    })
  }
  render() {
    console.log("hai"+this.state.details)
    return (
      <Container>
      <a href="#" onClick={this.props.artist}>  
         <Row>
          <Row><img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL +'/assets/images/+this.state.details.map(item=>item.dp)} onerror={this.src=process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/assets/img/'+this.state.eventdetails.map(item=>item.dp)}  className="banner-image-size-2"/></Row>
          <Row><img src={grad_banner}  className="grad-image-size-2"/></Row>
          <Col lg="4" className="round-image-padding-2"><img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL +'/assets/images/logo.png'} onerror={this.src=process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/assets/img/logo.png'}  className="round-image-size-2"/></Col>
          <Col lg="4" className="items-padding-2">
          <Row className="text-items-2">DJ SHERAM</Row>
          <Row className="text-items-2">Mumbai</Row>
          <Row className="text-items-2">Bollywood</Row>
          </Col>        
      </Row></a><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    </Container>
     );
    }
}
```

code:-(Layout)

```
class SingleLayout extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state= {details:this.props.match.params}
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <div>
        <Row>

            <Col xl="4" lg="4"><Row><Col lg='1'></Col><span>1 Artist playing</span></Row><br /><RelatedArtist data={this.state.eventdetails}/></Col>
          </Row>  
        <Row><AdBanner/></Row>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SingleEventsLayout;
```

code:-(slide)

```
export default class Sliders extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      Array:[],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('/getalllist')
    .then(res=>{
      this.state.Array = res.data
      this.forceUpdate()
    })
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.Array)
    const settings = {
      className: "center",
      centerMode: true,
      infinite: true,
      centerPadding: "24%",
      slidesToShow: 1,
      speed: 5000,
      width:"851px",
      infinite: true,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 7000,
      nextArrow:false
    };
    return (
      <div className="r-slider-main-section">
        <Slider {...settings}>
        {this.state.Array.map(item=>
          <div className="r-slider-spacer">
          <Link to={{pathname:"/events/"+(item.city.city_name)+"/"+(item._id)  ,state: { Id: item._id}}}>
            <Card style={{borderRadius:"17px"}}>
            <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL +'/assets/images/'+item.banner} onerror={this.src=process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/assets/img/logo.png'} className="r-test1" />
            <img src={image1} className="r-test2"></img>
            <img src={calender} className="r-calender-place"></img>
            <text className="r-text-month">DEC</text>
            <text className="r-text-date">{item.date_time_start.substring(8, 10)}</text>
            <text className="r-text-event-name">@{item.name}</text>
            <text className="r-text-event-detail">{item.type} featuring {item.name}</text>
            <div className="r-rectangle-icon"><div class="r-rectangle"><div className="r-rectangle-text">{item.amount}</div></div></div>
          </Card></Link>
        </div>)}
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In here I am passing props from slider to layout then to next one, but I don't know why it shows like this. I have given axios call inside componentDidMount but still it happening.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see this.state.details.map anywhere in your code. Where do you use that?

Comment: sorry.. it was this.state.eventDetail i have edited the code

Comment: ya . its an array so thats why i am using

Comment: If it's supposed to be an array, initialize it in the `constructor` with: `details: []`, not `details: ''`

Comment: ok i have done it but still same error

Answer (score 0):

You are doing many mistakes in your code.

1. Never mutate the state directly
2. You are doing map on string
3. You are not checking whether the data contains array of objects and only then do map

Can you try with below corrected code.

```
export default class Banner extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      passedId: this.props.data.id,
      details:[],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    let data={
      id:this.state.passedId
    }
    axios.post('/getoneartist' ,data)
    .then(res=>{
      this.setState({details:res.data})
      this.forceUpdate()
    })
  }
  render() {
    console.log("hai"+this.state.details)
    return (
      <Container>
      <a href="#" onClick={this.props.artist}>  
         {this.state.details && (<Row>
          <Row><img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL +'/assets/images/+this.state.details.map(item=>item.dp)} onerror={this.src=process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/assets/img/'+this.state.details.map(item=>item.dp)}  className="banner-image-size-2"/></Row>
          <Row><img src={grad_banner}  className="grad-image-size-2"/></Row>
          <Col lg="4" className="round-image-padding-2"><img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL +'/assets/images/logo.png'} onerror={this.src=process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/assets/img/logo.png'}  className="round-image-size-2"/></Col>
          <Col lg="4" className="items-padding-2">
          <Row className="text-items-2">DJ SHERAM</Row>
          <Row className="text-items-2">Mumbai</Row>
          <Row className="text-items-2">Bollywood</Row>
          </Col>        
      </Row>)}</a><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
    </Container>
     );
    }
}
```

Code: slide:

```
export default class Sliders extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      Array:[],
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    axios.get('/getalllist')
    .then(res=>{
      this.setState({ Array: res.data });
    })
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.Array)
    const settings = {
      className: "center",
      centerMode: true,
      infinite: true,
      centerPadding: "24%",
      slidesToShow: 1,
      speed: 5000,
      width:"851px",
      infinite: true,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
      autoplaySpeed: 7000,
      nextArrow:false
    };
    return (
      <div className="r-slider-main-section">
        <Slider {...settings}>
        {this.state.Array && this.state.Array.map(item=>
          <div className="r-slider-spacer">
          <Link to={{pathname:"/events/"+(item.city.city_name)+"/"+(item._id)  ,state: { Id: item._id}}}>
            <Card style={{borderRadius:"17px"}}>
            <img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL +'/assets/images/'+item.banner} onerror={this.src=process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/assets/img/logo.png'} className="r-test1" />
            <img src={image1} className="r-test2"></img>
            <img src={calender} className="r-calender-place"></img>
            <text className="r-text-month">DEC</text>
            <text className="r-text-date">{item.date_time_start.substring(8, 10)}</text>
            <text className="r-text-event-name">@{item.name}</text>
            <text className="r-text-event-detail">{item.type} featuring {item.name}</text>
            <div className="r-rectangle-icon"><div class="r-rectangle"><div className="r-rectangle-text">{item.amount}</div></div></div>
          </Card></Link>
        </div>)}
        </Slider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Code - layout

```
class SingleLayout extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state= {details:this.props.match.params}
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <div>
        <Row>

            <Col xl="4" lg="4"><Row><Col lg='1'></Col><span>1 Artist playing</span></Row><br /><RelatedArtist data={this.state.details}/></Col>
          </Row>  
        <Row><AdBanner/></Row>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default SingleEventsLayout;
```

Comment: no its not working i am getting error      Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: i have already updated the question answer still the same is it because of props?

Comment: delay in props or something?

Comment: i got it.. in that page now its fine. i assigned that data like this - - -  this.state.detail=res.data.artist

Comment: Man you need to learn basics first. You are not recommended to directly modify the state value like this.state.detail=res.data.artist. This is absolutely incorrect you need to use setState to modify the state value in react. You need to learn basics for doing things in right way